# Windows 10 1909 OS Corruption Preventing Further Updates

Tags: windows-10, upgrade, corruption, unattended-upgrades

We have multiple computers on the domain which have corruption within the OS. This corruption prevents the install of updates or upgrades.

I know the computers which have issues from the results of the command

```
DISM /online /cleanup-image /scanhealth
```

This reports that the component store is repairable. After extensive research online, I found several suggestions on how to repair this. I have tried all of the following, but none of this worked.

```
sfc /scannow
Dism.exe /online /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup 
Dism.exe /online /Cleanup-Image /AnalyzeComponentStore
```

With sfc /scannow inbetween.

```
DISM /online /Cleanup_image /RestoreHealth
```

Tried targeting an image file with:

```
DISM /online /Cleanup_Image /RestoreHealth /Source:ESD:D:\sources\Install.esd:6 
DISM /online /Cleanup_Image /RestoreHealth /Source:ESD:C:\esd\Install.esd:6
```

All of these fail, the restore health options always report source files cannot be found.

Eventually, on one of the effected machines, I was able to force the update to install using the Windows Update Assistant tool. This is okay for my individual computer, but we might have to apply this to multiple computers and automate the process.

Can anyone advise how we can do this since the upgrade cannot be deployed using SCCM and the other SCCM option of using a task sequence overwrites everything?

The restore health DISM commands were tried logged in as local admin, domain admin normal user, AV disabled, AV enabled. None of these worked. All I can think of is maybe I need a different source file, but I don't know where to get this from. Generally the computers have Windows 10 1909 installed, I only seem to be able to download the latest ISO for Windows 10.

It is potentially one of these updates that causes the corruption:

KB4580325
KB4580330
KB4578974
KB4577667
KB4577671
KB4580325
KB4577668
KB4579976
KB4580398
KB4580325
KB4577670
KB4578968
KB4578974
KB4579311

Comment: I assume the "/Soruce:" above is a typo! 
Breaking the Windows Update system takes a fair amount of doing. 
Since you're using SCCM, do you have the option to simply "re-image" the affected machines and rebuild them?

Comment: Do you have an idea about what has corrupted Windows in your environement ?

Comment: Hi, sorry, yes the "soruce" is a typo, I was copying the commands from a document I was writing up. I think that one of the updates is causing the corruption as I have monitored a group of computers which failed to install the updates and compared against a report I had compiled the previous day and it showed that computers that were okay that day now have this problem.

Comment: We can't re-image the laptops easily as every single person in the business is a remote worker. We don't have SCCM available over https, it is on the internal network only. I could deploy a task sequence that people can run while connected over DA, but the problem is that this would erase the files and I also don't think the business is okay about the time it takes.